# How to install RPM based Packages on OpenFiler

Tags: rpm

We bought One SuperMicro Server that will be used for Storage purposes and then we install the openfiler on it.

The thing is that we need to install RAID controller and Im not familiar with OpenFiler and there are packages in that are .rpm or .deb

when i pass the command **rpm -ivh StorMan-7.30.i386.rpm** it say

**-bash: rpm: command not found**

So how to install .rpm packages on this Openfiler. So that I can remotely access the RAID controller using my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If rpm is not found, it maybe not be supported (`OpenFiler may not be a derivative of RedHat`)

So a possible way but dangerous is to extract the binary file and copy it onto your machine,

i.e `rpm2cpio StorMan-7.30.i386.rpm  | cpio -idmv`, and copy everything extracted to `/`.

Be sure to test it on a testing environment first, it could ruin your system.